# Custom print() of DynamicArray in Kotlin prints unexpected result

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I have a simple scenario where I have Kotlin class DynamicArray.kt:

```
class DynamicArray(size: Int) {

    private var numArray: IntArray
    private var count: Int = 0

    init {
        if (size <= 0)
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for array size")    
        numArray = IntArray(size)
    }

    fun insert(item: Int) {
        if (numArray.size == count){

            // Create newArray with double size
            val newArray = IntArray(count * 2)

            // copy old to new
            for ((index, i) in numArray.withIndex()){
                newArray[index] = i
            }

            // assign newArray to old
            numArray = newArray

        }
        numArray[count++] = item
    }

    fun print(): String {
        val arrayAsString = StringBuilder()
        arrayAsString.append("[")
        for ((index, i) in numArray.withIndex()){
            arrayAsString.append(i)
            if (index != (count - 1)){
                arrayAsString.append(", ")
            }
        }
        arrayAsString.append("]")
        return arrayAsString.toString()
    }
}
```

And a simple Main.kt class which only have:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val array = DynamicArray(3)

    array.insert(1)
    array.insert(2)
    array.insert(3)

    println(array.print())

}
```

The above code works perfect when `size` of DynamicArray and `items` are eqaul it prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

but when we insert more items the initial size e.g:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val array = DynamicArray(3)

    array.insert(1)
    array.insert(2)
    array.insert(3)
    array.insert(4)

    println(array.print())

}
```

it prints weird values like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 40, 0, ]
```

#### Update

if I change the print method to:

```
fun print(): String {
        return numArray.contentToString() // using built-in method
}
```

it still prints :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

Un-able to figure out what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's look at *how you can find out* where the problem is.

There are many techniques for debugging, but by far the most useful in general is simply printing stuff out.  In order to narrow down where the problem is, it's really really really useful to be able to see the *state* of the program — in this case, the contents of the DynamicArray — at each point.

What you'd like to be able to do is to add a line such as:

```
println("Point A: $array")
```

…before and after each call to `insert()`.  The trouble is that that just prints something like:

```
Point A: DynamicArray@63947c6b
```

…which is because the DynamicArray doesn't override `toString()`.  You could instead call your `print()` method — but you don't know whether the bug is in there or not.

If DynamicArray were a `data class`, you'd get a shiny `toString()` implementation automatically.  But this class wouldn't really fit as a data class (and would need lots of other changes).  But there's nothing stopping you from writing your own, e.g.:

```
override fun toString() = "DynamicArray(count=$count, numArray=[${numArray.joinToString()}])"
```

With that in place, you can add lots of debugging output.  For example:

```
Start: DynamicArray(count=0, numArray=[0, 0, 0])
Inserted 1: DynamicArray(count=1, numArray=[1, 0, 0])
Inserted 2: DynamicArray(count=2, numArray=[1, 2, 0])
Inserted 3: DynamicArray(count=3, numArray=[1, 2, 3])
Inserted 4: DynamicArray(count=4, numArray=[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0])
Inserted 5: DynamicArray(count=5, numArray=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 50, ]
```

From that, it becomes a lot clearer where the problem is!  You can see that both `count` and `numArray` are getting set correctly.  So the problem must be in your `print()` method.

I'm not going to give the final solution here, as I think it would help you much more to work out the rest yourself; I hope this has given you enough of a start to do that.  (If you want a hint, consider how many numbers it prints, and where it puts the commas.)

Comment: I have no idea _whose answer should I mark as __Accepted__ all are equally appreciated_, but this is the suitable for __Accepted__, because it will give a chance to `Think like a programmer`

Answer (score 2):

The size of the array is doubled when a new item is inserted that does not fit. This means the size of the internal array may be *larger* than the virtual size of your DynamicArray.

To show only the *added* elements you should iterate from 0 to `count`, not iterate over the entire array.

An example that appends manually:

```
fun print(): String {
    val builder = StringBuilder()
    // Iterate over *inserted* indices only
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        if (builder.isNotEmpty()) {
            builder.append(", ")
        }
        builder.append(numArray[i])
    }
    builder.insert(0, "[")
    builder.append("]")
    return builder.toString()
}
```

Alternative using built-ins: (this does create an intermediary list)

```
fun print(): String {
    // get a List of added elements
    val content = numArray.take(count)
    // convert the list to a string
    return content.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]")
}
```

Comment: I have no idea _whose answer should I mark as __Accepted__ all are equally appreciated_

Answer (score 1):

Your print method iterates over all elements even if the count is less, hence zeros are appended to the printed string. Simple solution with minimal change to your code would be to break the loop if the index is greater than count

```
fun print(): String {
    val arrayAsString = StringBuilder()
    arrayAsString.append("[")
    for ((index, i) in numArray.withIndex()){
        if(index>=count) break;    // NEW condition
        arrayAsString.append(i)
        if (index != (count - 1)){
            arrayAsString.append(", ")
        }
    }
    arrayAsString.append("]")
    return arrayAsString.toString()
}
```

Here is a simpler code to `DynamicArray` class using Kotlin's in-build features

```
class DynamicArray(size: Int) {

  private var numArray: IntArray
  private var count: Int = 0

  init {
    require(size>0) { "Invalid value for array size" }
    numArray = IntArray(size)
  }

  fun insert(item: Int) {
    if (numArray.size == count) {
      numArray = numArray.copyInto(IntArray(count * 2))
    }
    numArray[count++] = item
  }

  fun print() = numArray.take(count).joinToString(", ", "[", "]")
}
```

Comment: I have no idea _whose answer should I mark as __Accepted__ all are equally appreciated_

Comment: @gidds answer is the best as he correctly gave the steps to debug. It will help you in future for sure instead of these solutions

Comment: That is __awesome__, this is the only thing which makes SO as great place for learning. _Happy Coding_